# 日本語に違和感:『あなたの回答をすでに含んでいる可能性のある質問』

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問する時に現れたので『あなたの』ではなく『あなたへの』の方がいいと思いますが。

故に私が回答していない物を含んでいますので・・・。

Answer (score 4):

ひとまず、以下はどうでしょうか。

> 以下の質問に既に回答がある可能性があります

Comment: 個人的に「あなたの」に違和感があるので、「この質問に対する〜」はいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 好みだと思いますが、「含んでいる可能性のある」の代わりに「含んでいるかもしれない」はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu たしかに、「この質問に対する」の方がよいかもしれません。編集します。

Comment: 『すでに』に違和感があります。「この質問に対する回答を含んでいる可能性のある過去の質問」ではいかがでしょうか。
「すでに」は「可能性のある質問」を修飾しているのに「すでに」と「質問」が離れた位置にあるのが原因だと思いましたので、２つを併せて「過去の質問」としてはどうかという案です。

Comment: @Fumu7 たしかに、そこはかとなく読みやすくなった感じがします。編集いたします。

Comment: 「あなた」も「この質問」も要らないと思います。
「以下の質問に既に回答がある可能性があります」はいかがでしょう。

Comment: @masm 編集して、 transifex (翻訳サービス) にも登録を行いました。次のデプロイで繁栄されるはずです。